# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на картинку, она менялась только у текущего вопроса?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой вот скрипт. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на картинку, она менялась только у текущего вопроса.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion h3:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();
    img = $('.accordion img');
    $(".accordion h3").click(function() {
        if(img.hasClass('img')){
                img.removeClass('img').addClass('down');
                img.attr('src', "./images/appActive_<?=$lang?>.png");
            } else if(img.hasClass('down')) {
                img.removeClass('down').addClass('img');
                img.attr('src', "./images/appPassive_<?=$lang?>.gif");

            }
        $(this).prev("p").slideToggle("slow")
            .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");


        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");

    });

});
</script>
```

Прошу прощения, забыл.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <span><?=$title?></span>
    <p><?=$content?></p>
    <h3><img class="img" src="images/faq/answerActive_eng.gif" alt=""></h3>
</div>
```

И Css:

```
 .accordion {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 595px;
}
.accordion h3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    border-bottom: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion span {
    font-family: "Vernada", Trebuchet, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #84B149;
}
.accordion h3:hover {
    background-color: #e3e2e2;
}
.accordion h3.active {
    background-position: right 5px;
}
.accordion p {
    position: relative;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    margin: 0;
    padding:  10px 15px 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
    border-right: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
}
```

Comment: немного HTML не помешало бы

Comment: Добавьте структуру html. 
Основная задача заменить строку 
img = $('.accordion img'); 
отдавать туда не все картинки, а только одну привязанную к текущему "h3" - но выборку правильную без знания структуры html написать нереально :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion h3:first").addClass("active");
    $(".accordion p:not(:first)").hide();
    //img = $('.accordion img'); убираем эту строку
    $(".accordion h3").click(function() {
        img = $(this).find('img'); // получаем нужную картинку
        if(img.hasClass('img')){
                img.removeClass('img').addClass('down');
                img.attr('src', "./images/appActive_<?=$lang?>.png");
            } else if(img.hasClass('down')) {
                img.removeClass('down').addClass('img');
                img.attr('src', "./images/appPassive_<?=$lang?>.gif");

            }
        $(this).prev("p").slideToggle("slow")
            .siblings("p:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

        $(this).siblings("h3").removeClass("active");

    });

});
</script>
```

Судя по стилям, классы 'img' и 'down' на картинке нужны только для определения, какую показывать. Если это верно, то можно упростить до 1 класса

```
if(img.hasClass('img')){
  img.attr('src', "./images/appActive_<?=$lang?>.png");
} else {
  img.attr('src', "./images/appPassive_<?=$lang?>.gif");
}
img.toggleClass('img');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
...
var img;
$(".accordion h3").click(function() {
    img = $(this).find('img');// $('img', this);
    ...
```

- [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

Comment: А что есть "вопрос"? Это содержимое "p" или "span"?
Если нужно изначально иметь все вопросы скрытые - пропиши для соответствующего элемента в СSS

.accordion p {display:none;} // если вопрос в параграфе

Comment: В данном скрипте,просто надо убрать not(:first).